# 404 when trying to utilize POST in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask app with this code

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def sortBy(a):
    return a['score']

def sort():
    f=open('/home/davisbanana/mysite/templates/scores.txt', 'r')
    resList=json.load(f)
    f.close();
    res = sorted(resList, key=sortBy)
    return res



@app.route("/send", methods=["POST"])
def saveR():
    f=open('/home/davisbanana/mysite/templates/scores.txt', 'r')
    resList=json.load(f)
    f.close();
    resList.append(request.json)
    f=open('/home/davisbanana/mysite/templates/scores.txt', 'w')
    json.dump(resList,f)
    f.close()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    scores = sort()
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html", scores=scores)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Even when trying to go directly to the post method(mysite.com/send), instead of returning a 405 it returns a 404

Comment: by the way, in your `index()` function... you should change `scores = sort()` to be `scores.sort()`

Comment: How are you posting to your `send` route? why are you redirecting from your post method instead of handling a response? What errors does your app throw when you make the post request? Trying to directly go to the page is a get request so wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `if request.method == "POST":` in your `saveR` function:

In other words, it should be like this:

```
def saveR():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f=open('file.json', 'r')
        resList=json.load(f)
        f.close();
        resList.append(request.json)
        f=open('file.json', 'w')
        json.dump(resList,f)
        f.close()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: After changing the code, it still proceeds to give out the 404.

Comment: try running your app with `app.run(debug=True)`, then it is going to tell you the error while accessing your page. Please share the screenshot of the error

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to debugging, how do I go around doing that? While I added the line to my app, I'm not sure how to access the debug info.

Comment: Just execute the app with the `app.run(debug=True)`, then access your page. You will have the error log displayed right there

Comment: You shouldnt need to add a check to see if the reqeust is a post request.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will (additionally to the `POST` request) try to make a `GET` request.

Just add `GET` to the methods of the endpoint:

```python
@app.route("/send", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def saveR():
    f=open('/home/davisbanana/mysite/templates/scores.txt', 'r')
    resList=json.load(f)
    f.close();
    resList.append(request.json)
    f=open('/home/davisbanana/mysite/templates/scores.txt', 'w')
    json.dump(resList,f)
    f.close()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: I figured as much, but even after adding the GET method, it stills directs me to a 404.

Comment: no. if done correctly a post request shouldnt try to make a get request